# Intellij JavaFX Setup - Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, javafx

I am just starting to learn how to use JavaFX in Intellij. I added the JavaFX to the project structure, then in configurations in VM options I added

> "--module-path "my path to /lib" --add-modules
> javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"

But whenever I try to run the Main.java i get the error:

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
> Unrecognized option: --module-path

Comment: What is the version of your JDK, I would try updating the JDK, the `--module-path` option is added after a certain version.

Comment: I was using JDK 8, installed 11 and it everything works now, thanks!